# My app crashes in Android 4.4.2 but not in 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, xml

My App works in Android 5.1.1.

In 4.4.2 it crashes on launch.

This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.medialablk.onlineshoppin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List < Sites > sitesList = new ArrayList < > ();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SitesAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new SitesAdapter(sitesList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
            getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareSitesData();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string
            .navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView
            .OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    int id = item.getItemId();

                    if (id == R.id.nav_preferences) {
                        // Handle the preference  action
                    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                        // Handle the About action
                    }

                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(
                        R.id.drawer_layout);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(
            getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener
            .ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                    if (checkNet()) {
                        Sites sites = sitesList.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            BrowserActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("url", sites.getUrl());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            BrowserActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("url",
                            "file:///android_asset/index.html"
                        );
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            }));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void prepareSitesData() {
        Sites sites = new Sites(0, "Takas.lk", "www.takas.lk",
            "http://takas.lk/", R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(1, "Wow.lk", "www.wow.lk", "http://wow.lk/", R.drawable
            .me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(2, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "#",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(3, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "#",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(4, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "1",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(5, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "1",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(6, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "1",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(7, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "1",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        sites = new Sites(8, "OnlineShopping.lk",
            "Online Shopping Sri Lanka Online Shopping Sri Lanka", "1",
            R.drawable.me);
        sitesList.add(sites);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean checkNet() {
        boolean mobileNwInfo;
        ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
            CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            mobileNwInfo = false;
        }
        return mobileNwInfo;
    }
}
```

App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medialablk.onlineshopping"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: What is error in logcat ?

Comment: put the logcat error here to best help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, make sure all your library version must be same in gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```